# Python: Indexing error on only first call of class property

Tags: python, arrays, properties

I have a class which generates a 2D array for a certain property on the first call of that property, the saves the matrix for later calls. The first time I call it I'd like to already be indexing the first dimension of the array. However, I get the following indexing error:

IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed

Here's some sample code:

```
import numpy as np

class rand_matrix:

    _matrix = None
    _xsize = 5

    @property
    def matrix(self):
        if self._matrix is None:
            self._matrix = np.random.normal(0, 1, (self._xsize, 100))

        return self._matrix

    def sum_matrix(self):
        count = 0.0
        for i in range(self._xsize):
            count += np.sum(self.matrix[i])
        return count
```

Clearly this isn't the most straight forward way to sum a matrix, so please don't concentrate on that. If I were to call `sum_matrix` before calling `matrix`, then `_matrix` would be `None`, get generated and returned by `matrix` as an array. But (I think) since the instance that is generating `_matrix` as an array from `None` is the same that indexes that array, I am getting this indexing error. If I then go call `sum_matrix` again it works.

Is there some way to get this to work the first time?

Thanks very much for any advice.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error from your current example code.

Comment: I can not replicate your error, can you be more clear?

Comment: Typo on line `count += np.sum(self.matrix[i])`? Should that be `_matrix`?  Also, why not just initialilze `_matrix` during `__init__` and be done with it?

Comment: @RobertB. Using `_matrix` would defeat the whole purpose of the computed property - so definitely not a typo.

Comment: Sorry about that, you're right this code seems to run fine. I'll need to investigate further the cause of the indexing error.